# Only one instance of the application

Tags: android, android-manifest

I found many threads about this but none solved my problem.

My application is an online radio, and clicking on the menu or go to the homepage of the device, the radio still playing, and that's what it should be.

But when clicking on the application icon, opens a new instance of the application, should return only when the instance is already open, it makes them two radios playing at once. To finish then the first instance of the application is necessary to go to the Manage Applications menu and terminate the application.

I've tried using launchMode as singleTask, singleTop, SingleInstance, but none works.

How could I solve this problem?

I appreciate any help.

Below my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.radiomiriam"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.3"  >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-feature />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo_novo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.radiomiriam.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.radiomiriam.Nsi"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.radiomiriam.Contato"
            android:label="@string/contato" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Dear friends, place the wrong problem here. Sorry.

The problem occurred only when clicking the back button, then put the following function in my activity:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and is working 100% now.

Many thanks to all who responded.

Comment: just a suggestion, I never tried it. Extends application class, and give him a boolean attribute like "opened", then in onCreate of your launch actiity ask to application if it is opened, if not, set opened to true and start the activity, if already opened, finish your launching activity

Comment: You need to set a flag up that gets checked by your service every time your application UI gets launched.

Comment: Could you add the relevant parts of your AndroidManifest.xml to your question here?

Comment: "opens a new instance of the application" -- no, it does not. There can be at most once instance of the application running as a process. It may well create another instance of an activity.

Comment: Should this be the activity is performed more than once

Comment: Do you want your radio to stop when clicking on the application icon, just like when it starts the first time.

Comment: How do you know there's another instance of your application? Can you switch between the running instances using the Recents button? Also, I didn't see any service declaration in you manifest. Do you use any?

Comment: Joe, do not use service yet, but I now use to solve the problem.

Comment: I was trying a simpler solution because it does not have much experience with android yet. So not sure how to create a service, but it seems that I have to learn now.

Comment: Problem solved, edited with the solution, thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try service that runs in background as radio need to play in background ,and on click stop the service and restart all.

Comment: I'll try that, I did not want to restart the service because it will take a break from radio and restart, and do not get cute. But it seems the solution

Comment: I did not use a service, but it would be a solution for sure, thanks anyway.

Comment: what do u need to do when the button is clicked

Comment: When you press the back button, and returns to the application, the activity is performed again so that there are two instances of the radio playing at the same time. With that function up there, the problem was solved by having back often for the same activity.

Answer (score 1):

In the manifest add the line below to the appropriate activity

```
android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
```

Comment: It did not work well, I'll try to use a service and check this service running every startup activity